# matching string except spaces and tabs that follow

Tags: regex

Sample string, at the beginning of line is TAB, and between `maxLen = 256` and `;` are either spaces or tabs.

I need to match only the `"TABmaxLen = 256"` portion irgnoring the rest

`maxLen = 256                 ; Maximum string size + 1`

My regex doesn't work for some reason because it matches all up to `;` includign spaces and tabs, but I need to ignore spaces and tabs before and including `;`

`(\t.*)(?!\s\t);`

`TABmaxLen = 256` is just a sample, it should match anything except spaces and tabs that follow and end with `;`

**EDIT:**

More information:

This is sample ASM code, per line, I want to match only those lines which have inline comments, but only code, not spaces and tabs and not inline comments.

```
; a function result to a C + + program.
    option casemap:none
    nl = 10                      ; ASCII code for newline
    maxLen = 256                 ; Maximum string size + 1
    
    .data
    titleStr byte 'Listing 1 - 8', 0
```

regex should match from example above these 2 (including starting tab):

```
    nl = 10
    maxLen = 256
```

Comment: Can you share multiple matching and not-matching samples?

Comment: Like this? `\t([^\s;][^;]*?)\s*;` https://regex101.com/r/fZFnFI/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird yeah that's the problem, because spaces and tabs should not be matched.

Comment: @lemon added more info thanks

Comment: @metablaster You can get the capture group 1 value here https://regex101.com/r/hwYYhD/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the tab, then capture any char except `;` and match the ending whitespace chars until the `;`

```
\t([^\s;][^;]*?)\s*;
```

**Explanation**

- `\t` Match a tab
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s;][^;]*?` Match a single non whitespace char other than `;` followed by matching any char other than `;` non greedy
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s*;` Match optional whitespace chars followed by `;`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hwYYhD/1).

Another option for a match only and lookarounds and asserting 1 or more whitespace chars at the end followed by `;`

```
(?<=\t)[^\s;].*?(?=\s+;)
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2KpmcM/1)

Comment: from what I see capture group 1 also captures spaces and tabs after code line up to semicolon, but I need to capture code only, without spaces or tabs that precede semicolon.

Comment: @metablaster Then you can use the second pattern with the lookaround if that is supported. Or use `\w(?:.*?\w)?(?=\s*;)` without a lookbehind assertion https://regex101.com/r/EPgLJX/1

Comment: Yep, that works! now I hope it will work with C++ regex but you have given me good hint, thanks!

Comment: For reference, I'm adding the following which also worked `^\t(.*?)(?=\s*;)`